# Java runtime.getruntime() gives no output

Tags: java

I am trying to execute a curl command as a Process through Java. When I execute it, I am not getting back any output at all. When I execute the same command through the command line I am getting the proper output. The URL returns the output as XML.

Here is the code for my Java program.

```
public static void exec(){
        try {
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"curl", "http://genome.ucsc.edu/cgi-bin/das/mm9/dna\\?segment\\=chr1:3206424,3206499"});
            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            String line=null;
            while((line=input.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Here is the command I am executing through the command line

```
curl http://genome.ucsc.edu/cgi-bin/das/mm9/dna\?segment\=chr1:3206424,3206499
```

When I run the Java program using the following String array `{"ls", "-al"}` it gives me the expected output

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: you need to bind the process' outputstream to your buffered reader. Not its input stream

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't waiting for the `Process` to complete. Also, you could use [`ProcessBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) and `inheritIO()` like

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("curl",
        "http://genome.ucsc.edu/cgi-bin/das/mm9/dna?"
        + "segment=chr1:3206424,3206499");
pb.inheritIO();
try {
    Process p = pb.start();
    p.waitFor();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Edit**

From your comment below, you'd need another `Thread`. Something like,

```
static class InputStreamReaderRunnable implements Runnable {
    private StringBuilder sb;
    private InputStream is;

    public InputStreamReaderRunnable(InputStream is) {
        this.is = is;
        this.sb = new StringBuilder();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        String line;
        try {
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line).append(System.lineSeparator());
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return sb.toString();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("curl",
            "http://genome.ucsc.edu/cgi-bin/das/mm9/dna?segment=chr1:3206424,3206499");
    try {
        Process p = pb.start();
        InputStreamReaderRunnable isrr = new InputStreamReaderRunnable(
                p.getInputStream());
        Thread t = new Thread(isrr);
        t.start();
        p.waitFor();
        t.join();
        String out = isrr.toString();
        System.out.println(out);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: @AndroidDev93 Fix the URL like I did in my answer; I just ran it (and *brother* I get output; I don't understand it, but I get it).

Comment: Ah, you're right! But, it automatically gets printed to the command line. I'm not able to store the output into a String. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: @AndroidDev93 Edited. That is a bit more complicated.

Comment: I am pretty sure this can be done much simpler without multi-threading.  Wouldn't the OP's original code work fine if they added `.waitFor()`?

Comment: @Brandon Also must fix the url. It does seem to work, but I've had issues with using the `main()` thread to read a sub-process output.

Comment: @Brandon is right, changing the URL and adding .waitFor() solved the problem. The threading wasn't required.